# Cleaning fan motor

Tags: electric-motor

I am cleaning an old discontinued bathroom fan motor and the housing of the copper ring of the shaft has tightly packed hair. I started cleaning it up but it's so tightly packed I am having second thoughts.
Is that supposed to be there?
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think it might be a washer(felt?).  There seems to be a hard cut off line on the inner circle of felt, where collected hair should be messy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not hair -- at least not human hair -- but a fibrous reservoir to hold oil. The center bushing is sintered bronze, a metal made by squeezing bronze powder together until it forms a porous solid. The oil is slowly wicked into the porous bronze from the reservoir as the oil is consumed by friction with the rotating shaft.

You can extend the life of this motor by adding light oil to the fiber reservoir. There's sometimes a sticker on such a motor with instructions such as "Oil 30 drops per year" or some such. You don't want to saturate the fibers so that the oil drips out, but you want enough that it can be wicked into the bronze.

Any light machine oil will do. Sewing machine oil would be ideal.